# ¿Como seleccionar los valores contenidos en un XML?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Buenas tardes colegas estoy tratando de obtener los valores contenidos en un XML por medio de la sentencia select sin embargo la consulta solo me arroja valores nulos.

```
DECLARE @xml XML

SET @xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Values version="2.0">
<array name="results" type="record" depth="1">
    <record javaclass="com.wm.util.Values">
        <value name="shiftId">5c642c6110c2c1b6120000ec</value>
        <value name="shiftnumber">S-WCKBHMD</value>
        <value name="createdat">2019-02-13T14:40:33.356Z</value>
        <value name="total">$13,566,582,391.00</value>
        <value name="TotalTaxes">$1,871,253,000.00</value>
        <value name="stationid">5bb4fb8f800da28e05af19ea</value>
        <value name="closed">true</value>
        <value name="channel">callcenter</value>
    </record>
    <record javaclass="com.wm.util.Values">
        <value name="shiftId">5c757323f42b61591c000041</value>
        <value name="shiftnumber">S-XVPBERP</value>
        <value name="createdat">2019-02-26T17:10:59.965Z</value>
        <value name="total">$24,316,266,073.00</value>
        <value name="TotalTaxes">$3,353,970,000.00</value>
        <value name="stationid">5bb4fb8f800da28e05af19ea</value>
        <value name="closed">true</value>
        <value name="channel">callcenter</value>
    </record>
    <record javaclass="com.wm.util.Values">
        <value name="shiftId">5c7ec8709ad07e9711000013</value>
        <value name="shiftnumber">S-TBTNC3T</value>
        <value name="createdat">2019-03-05T19:05:20.033Z</value>
        <value name="total">$291,624,000.00</value>
        <value name="TotalTaxes">$40,224,000.00</value>
        <value name="stationid">5bb4fb8f800da28e05af19ea</value>
        <value name="closed">true</value>
        <value name="channel">callcenter</value>
    </record>
</array>
</Values>'

 SELECT 
    shiftId = Node.Data.value('(shiftId)[1]', 'CHAR(50)'),
    shiftnumber = Node.Data.value('(shiftnumber)[1]', 'CHAR(50)'),
    createdat = Node.Data.value('(createdat)[1]', 'datetime')
 FROM @xml.nodes('Values/array/record') Node(Data)

 [![Resultado de la consulta][1]][1]
```

Answer (score 1):

La idea esta casi bien, pero estas intentando seleccionar por la property name no por la tag del xml, seria sacar por la tag "value" y moverte por el array generado según posición.

Ejemplo:

```
  SELECT 
    shiftId = Node.Data.value('(value)[1]', 'CHAR(50)'),
    shiftnumber = Node.Data.value('(value)[2]', 'CHAR(50)'),
    createdat = Node.Data.value('(value)[3]', 'datetime')
 FROM @xml.nodes('Values/array/record') Node(Data)
```

Espero que te ayude!